# Установка программ на Ubuntu в WSL под Windows 10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-10, wsl2

Сразу скажу, c ubuntu я знаком не очень хорошо.
Для отладки понадобилась недавно ubuntu 18.04. На рабочем компе стоит Windows 10, думал между виртуалкой и WSL2. После прочтения нескольких статей в интернете выбрал второе решение, как наиболее оптимальное. Собственно, установилось все легко и просто. Проблемы начались при попытке установить дополнительное по, например docker. В интернетах везде написано, что достаточно выполнить в таком случае

```
sudo apt install docker
```

но пока даже не важно, что именно устанавливать, на попытку установить любую программу я получаю следующий ответ:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package docker
```

Обновление пакетов также не работает. Думал, что может быть это связано с сетевыми настройками системы. Нашел решение, в котором предлагается редактировать файл resolv.conf, он открывается, но при попытке его сохранить, я всегда получаю ошибку no such file or directory.

Многие команды, через которые пытался решить вопрос я до конца не понимаю, поэтому не могу точнее сформулировать вопрос. Подскажите пожалуйста, в какую сторону вообще копать? В статьях, при описании установки ubuntu на wsl, у людей таких проблем не возникает. В чем может быть проблема? Спасибо!

Comment: А ты репозиторий с пакетами докер демона поключил?

Comment: Я вводил команду  
`sudo add-apt-repository universe` . На сайте packages.ubuntu.com указано, что в Ubuntu 18.04 bionic, пакет docker находится там.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо, вопрос решен!
Оказывается, все было просто и логично. В голой Ubuntu нет установщиков, есть только локальный список пакетов, доступных в репозитории для установки. Но и этот список изначально не актуальный.
Проблема была в том, что неправильно прописаны настройки сети. Надо прописать в файле **etc/resolf.conf** строчку `nameserver 8.8.8.8`.
Это публичный DNS сервер Google.

Вторая моя глупая ошибка была в том, что данный файл можно редактировать только от имени *root* пользователя. Поэтому когда я открывал файл командой `nano etc/resolf.conf` он и не сохранялся. Правильно `sudo nano etc/resolf.conf`

Далее прямая установка пакета типа **apt istall ...** все еще не сработает, потому что нужно обновить локальный список пакетов, доступных в репозитории для установки. Для этого выполняем команду `sudo apt update` и все начинает работать.
Я понимаю, что это все элементарно, но при незнании Ubuntu, на понимание данных процессов ушло пару часов. Поэтому оставлю это здесь, вдруг таким же, как я пригодится. Возможно, в чем-то я здесь не прав, но оно работает.